# onepage checkout is not working in magento 2

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-2.0

I am facing one page check out issues with Magento 2. I am enabled one-page checkout for the admin panel stroe->configuration-> sales-> enable one-page checkout. 
  After it when I checked it from the frontend there is nothing happened I check out running with three step.
can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Can You please give proper information and please give the screenshot for the same

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?